# Issue with Docker-compose and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

Please assist

I'm trying to run both react.js and nest.js on `http://localhost:3000` with docker-compose and Nginx, however
my react.js app isn't binding correctly. When I visit the link, I only see the nginx welcome page.

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:13.1-alpine
    env_file:
      - ./database/.env
    volumes:
      - "db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    networks:
      - challenge
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  backend:
    build:
      context: $PWD/../../backend
      dockerfile: $PWD/backend/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./backend/.env:/app/.env
      - ../../backend/src:/app/src
      - storage:/app/storage
    ports:
      - 3000
    networks:
      - challenge
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    environment:
      - FORCE_COLOR=1

  frontend:
    build:
      context: $PWD/../../web
      dockerfile: $PWD/frontend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3001
    networks:
      - challenge
    depends_on:
      - backend
    env_file:
      - ./frontend/.env
    volumes:
      - ../../web/src:/app/frontend/src

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    networks:
      - challenge

volumes:
  db-data:
  storage:

networks:
  challenge:
```

And this is my Dockerfile for the React

```
FROM node:14.18.1-alpine3.14 as build

WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY package.json /app/frontend/
COPY yarn.lock /app/frontend/

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . /app/frontend

RUN yarn run build

FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Also, this is my nginx.conf

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  client_max_body_size 1000M;
  server {
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location /api/v1 {
      proxy_pass http://backend:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

Please assist as I've tried changing the ports, and exposing different ports but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: To start with you can't have several services bind to the same port, you need to use different ports.

Comment: @super "Specify just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen for the host port)" - [compose file docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

Comment: Have you checked `docker logs <container>`? When I've had problems with this sort of thing in the past its often been down to the `nginx.conf`, might be worth posting that if no one comes up with an answer.

Comment: @super, I've updated the question as the original way I head it was with different ports

Comment: @Andy2K11 I'm not experiencing any errors for nginx, just the welcome page

Answer (score 0):

You have two nginx servers: one inside frontend service and another one inside nginx service. Is it intended?

I suppose you need to access the nginx service provided by frontend so in that case you need to go to:

http://localhost:3001

and map 3001:80 because 80 is the exposed port in that image.

Comment: No not really as this was part of a technical assessment, but I made changes to how it was implemented and there by having 2 nginx.confs. The one in the frontend shouldn't be in use. 

Though I managed to fix my issue, instead of building, I served the project and exposed the necessary port like you suggested and updated my nginx so that I have a similar location path as the backend one